# pgfplots error: Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Yesterday, I asked how to add numbers to the top of clustered bars in a bar graph with pgfplots in a MWE from the pgfplots manual, and got [great answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355947/numbers-centered-above-clustered-bar-graph-in-pgfplots/356021#356021). However, I've been unable to modify the solution to work for my graph; I get the error, "Missing number, treated as zero" right after `width = 0.8\textwidth]`. How can I fix this?

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      ymin=0,
      symbolic x coords={float,small int,int,latin string,string,heterogeneous},
      xtick=data]
      ylabel=CPU Cycles,
      legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
      ybar=5pt,% configures `bar shift'
      bar width=9pt,
      width = 0.8\textwidth
      ]
      \addplot[y1,fill=blue] coordinates {
        (float,42)
        (small int,50)
        (int,80)
        (latin string,80)
        (string,40)
        (heterogeneous,50)
      };
      \addplot[y2,fill=blue] coordinates {
        (float,42)
        (small int,50)
        (int,80)
        (latin string,80)
        (string,40)
        (heterogeneous,50)
      };

      \addplot [
      only marks,
      point meta=explicit,
      nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1]{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
      nodes near coords style={above}
      ]
      table[
      x=x,
      y expr={max(\thisrow{y1},\thisrow{y2})},
      % meta expr={(1-\thisrow{y2}/\thisrow{y1}) * 100}] {\mydata};
       meta expr={100*(1-\thisrow{y1}/\thisrow{y2})}] {\mydata};

      \legend{Far,Near}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The working version, which I'm trying to modify, is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\pgfplotstableread{
x y1 y2
1930 50e6 38e6
1940 33e6 42e6
1950 40e6 43e6
1960 50e6 45e6
1970 70e6 65e6
}\mydata

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=0,
    x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel=Population,
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar=5pt,% configures `bar shift'
    bar width=9pt,
]
\addplot table[x=x,y=y1] {\mydata};
\addplot table[x=x,y=y2] {\mydata};

\addplot [
  only marks,
  point meta=explicit,
  nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1,showpos]{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
  nodes near coords style={above}
  ]
  table[
    x=x,
    y expr={max(\thisrow{y1},\thisrow{y2})},
    meta expr={(\thisrow{y2}-\thisrow{y1})/\thisrow{y1} * 100}] {\mydata};

\legend{Far,Near}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `y1` and `y2` keys doesn't exist, and the final `\addplot` cannot work because you have no `\mydata` table.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks. I added the working code that I'm trying to modify, which defines those keys etc. Do you have any idea how I can correctly port it over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

- First of all, there's an extra `]` after `xtick=data` in the `axis` options. This means that the following options will not be read, so that must be removed.
- The code in [my answer to your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355947/numbers-centered-above-clustered-bar-graph-in-pgfplots/356021#356021) relies on storing the data in a `pgfplotstable` table. For example,

  ```
  \pgpflotstableread{
  A B C
  1 2 3
  2 3 4
  }\mydata
  ```

  This saves that table of data to the `\mydata` macro. The first row gives names to the columns. You can then plot one column versus another with e.g.

  ```
  \addplot table[x=A,y=B] {\myadata};
  ```

  So this means that the values in the `A` column is used as the x-coordinates, and those in the `B` column are used as y-coordinates.

  In your code, you've gone from `\addplot table[x=x,y=y1] {\mydata
  };`, to `\addplot [y1,...] coordinates {..};`, so you specify the coordinates manually instead of reading them from the table, but you've kept the `y1` argument, which actually referred to a specific column in the table. A table which you haven't defined.
- And because the table is not defined, the third `\addplot` doesn't work.

  #### Explanation of the code adding the numbers

  The numbers above the bars are added with the third `\addplot`:

  ```
  \addplot [
    only marks,
    point meta=explicit,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1,showpos]{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
    nodes near coords style={above}
    ]
    table[
      x=x,
      y expr={max(\thisrow{y1},\thisrow{y2})},
      meta expr={(\thisrow{y2}-\thisrow{y1})/\thisrow{y1} * 100}] {\mydata};
  ```

  - `only marks`: `ybar` is specified in the `axis`, but this shouldn't plot a bar.
  - `point meta=explicit`: The `point meta` defines what should be printed by `nodes near coords`, `explicit` means that the value is an explicit coordinate.
  - `nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1,showpos]{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}`: The `nodes near coords` option prints something next to the plot marker/bar. The part after `=` defines the formatting of the number fed to these nodes, represented by `\pgfplotspointmeta`. The `\pgfmathprintnumber` macro is for pretty-printing numbers, the `precision` determines the number of decimals, while `showpos` means that a plus sign is printed before positive numbers.
  - `nodes near coords style={above}`: positions the `nodes near coords` above the coordinate.
  - `table[<options>] {\mydata}` is explained above, but the `<options>` are a bit different:

    - `x=x`: use the column named `x` as x-coordinates
    - `y expr={max(\thisrow{y1},\thisrow{y2})}`: for y-coordinates, use not a specific value from the table, but the result of the expression given.  `\thisrow{y1}` returns the value from the given column, here `y1`, so `max(\thisrow{y1},\thisrow{y2})` is the maximum of `y1` and `y2`.
    - `meta expr={(\thisrow{y2}-\thisrow{y1})/\thisrow{y1} * 100}`: Similar to `y expr`, `meta expr` sets the `meta` value, which in the end defines the content of the `nodes near coords`, to the result of the given expression. So this is the `explicit` value of the `point meta`.

A working version of your code is the following. Note that I made up the values in the `y2` column, so you should edit those. Note also that because some of the x-values had spaces in them, I used a comma as a column separator, instead of the default space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
x,y1,y2
float,42,23
small int,50,60
int,80,30
latin string,80,90
string,40,45
heterogeneous,50,37
}\mydata

\begin{axis}[
      ymin=0,
      symbolic x coords={float,small int,int,latin string,string,heterogeneous},
      xtick=data,
      ylabel=CPU Cycles,
      legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
      ybar=5pt,% configures `bar shift'
      bar width=9pt,
      width = \textwidth,
      height= 0.6\textwidth
      ]

      \addplot[fill=blue] table[x=x,y=y1] {\mydata};
      \addplot[fill=red] table[x=x,y=y2] {\mydata};

      \addplot [
      only marks,
      point meta=explicit,
      nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1]{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
      nodes near coords style={above}
      ]
      table[
      x=x,
      y expr={max(\thisrow{y1},\thisrow{y2})},
      meta expr={(1-\thisrow{y1}/\thisrow{y2}) * 100}] {\mydata};


      \legend{Far,Near}
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that it is possible to get the `xticklabels` directly from the table, but then it must be saved in a text file instead of using `\pgfplotstableread`, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21220/using-labels-from-a-file-in-pgfplot/21224#21224